# How to build struct with variable 1 to 4 bytes in one value?

Tags: c#, .net

What I try to do:

I want to store very much data in RAM. For faster access and less memory footprint I need to use an array of struct values:

```
MyStruct[] myStructArray = new MyStruct[10000000000];
```

Now I want to store unsigned integer values with one, two, three or four bytes in MyStruct. But it should only use the less possible memory amount. When I store a value it one byte it should only use one byte and so on.

I could implement this with classes, but that is inappropriate here because the pointer to the object would need 8 bytes on a 64bit system. So it would be better to store just 4 bytes for every array entry. But I want to only store/use one/two/three byte when needed. So I can't use some of the fancy classes.

I also can't use one array with one bytes, one array with two bytes and so on, because I need the special order of the values. And the values are very mixed, so storing an additional reference when to switch to the other array would not help.

Is it possible what want or is the only way to just store an array of 4 byte uints regardless I only need to store one byte, two byte in about 60% of the time and three bytes in about 25% of the time?

Comment: Have you looked at [StructLayoutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx)?

Comment: It does not help in my case. I need a struct with one byte value, two byte values, three byte values and four byte values in one struct. But only using for example one byte when I store only one byte. I don't know how StructLayoutAttribute can help.

Comment: Which is your primary goal, lesser memory usage, or faster access?

Comment: Wasn't sure what you were looking for... But I don't think what you are looking for is possible. You need to look at some sort of packing algorithm - not using arrays at all.

Comment: @Dave currently it is lesser memory usage. I have some CPU cycles left.

Comment: What is this "special order"? Does it involve a set of rules that may help solve your problem?

Comment: The special order is that I want to use the index for incoming requests. When someone needs value 234241 I can fetch it without other lookups. Also I use this value as reference in my data files.

Comment: Is the data read only once its in memory? Your frequency of bytes used doesn't contain zero bytes so its maybe not sparse - can you tell us what the data corresponds to?

Comment: Once in memory the data is read only. There are no zero bytes. But I could change it so that there are zero bytes. The values correspond to their probability. So the int value 0 is the most common value. int value 1 is less common than int value 2 and so on. So most of my rows only need one byte (a bit above 30%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get close to that what you want if you are willing to sacrifice some additional CPU time and waste additional 2 or 4 bits per one stored value.

You could just use byte `byte[]` and combine it with [`BitArray` collection](http://www.dotnetperls.com/bitarray). In byte[] you would then just sequentially store one, two, three or four bytes and in BitArray denote in binary form (pairs of two bits) or just put a bit to value 1 to denote a new set of bytes have just started (or ended, however you implement it) in your data array.

However you could get something like this in memory:

```
byte[]   --> [byte][byte][byte][byte][byte][byte][byte]...
BitArray --> 1001101...
```

Which means you have 3 byte, 1 byte, 2 bytes etc. values stored in your byte array.

Or you could alternatively encode your bitarray as binary pairs to make it even smaller. This means you would vaste somewhere between 1.0625 and 1.25 bytes per your actual data byte.

It depends on your actual data (your `MyStruct`) if this will suffice. If you need to distinguish to which values in your struct those bytes really corresponds, you could waste some additional bits in `BitArray`.

**Update to your O(1) requirement:**

Use another index structure which would store one index for each N elements, for example 1000. You could then for example access item with index 234241 as

```
indexStore[234241/1000]
```

which gives you index of element 234000, then you just calculate the exact index of element 234241 by examining those few hundred elements in BitArray.

O(const) is acheieved this way, const can be controlled with density of main index, of course you trade time for space.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible. How would the CLR process the following expression?

```
myStructArray[100000]
```

If the elements are of variable size, the CLR cannot know the address of the 100000th element. Therefore array elements are of fixed size, always.

If you don't require `O(1)` access, you can implement variable-length elements on top of a `byte[]` and search the array yourself.

You could split the list into 1000 sublists, which are packed individually. That way you get `O(n/2000)` search performance on average. Maybe that is good enough in practice.

A "packed" array can only be searched in `O(n/2)` on average. But if your partial arrays are 1/1000th the size, it becomes `O(n/2000)`. You can pick the partial array in `O(1)` because they all would be of the same size.

Also, you can adjust the number of partial arrays so that they are individually about 1k elements in size. At that point the overhead of the array object and reference to it vanish. That would give you `O(1000/2 + 1)` lookup performance which I think is quite an improvement over `O(n/2)`. It is a **constant-time lookup** (with a big constant).

Comment: Exactly this is my problem. I currently think about building my array with byte[] myself. I would use the first bit of a byte to figure out if there is a second byte and so on. But currently I need O(1) access. Looping through the whole array would bring me an O(n/2) access time I think.

Comment: That is true and I believe it is not possible to have both space and time efficiency in this case. You could split the list into 1000 sublists, which are packed individually. That way you get O(n/2000) performance on average. Is that enough?

Comment: Currently I can't say, because I don't think it would be O(n/2000). When I have 10 Billion items, pack them in 1000 arrays I am left with 10 million items per sublist. Now each entry has a variable length. I think now the important part is the "search the array yourself" part. Do you have other/better suggestions for this than I would do it (using the first bit to indicate that there is one more byte and so on)?

Comment: A packed array can only be searched in O(n/2). But if your partial arrays are 1/1000th the size, it becomes O(n/2000). You can pick the partial array in O(1) because they all would be of the same size. Also, you can adjust the number of partial arrays so that they are individually about 1k elements in size. At that point the overhead of the array object and reference to it vanish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I give you an uovite, but I will accept the anwer from Darjan because the bitarray idea is better than my own idea how to use the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it.

If the data isn't sorted, and there is nothing more you can say about it, then you are not going to be able to do what you want.

Simple scenario:

```
array[3]
```

Should point to some memory address.  But, how would you know what are dimensions of `array[0]`-`array[2]`?  To store that information in an O(1) fashion, you would only waste MORE memory than you want to save in the first place.

You are thinking out of the box, and that's great.  But, my guess is that this is the wrong box that you are trying to get out of.  If your data is really random, and you want direct access to every array member, you'll have to use MAXIMUM width that is needed for your number for every number.  Sorry.

I had one similar situation, with having numbers of length smaller than 32 bits that I needed to store.  But they were all fixed width, so I was able to solve that, with custom container and some bit shifting.

HOPE:

http://www.dcc.uchile.cl/~gnavarro/ps/spire09.3.pdf

Maybe you can read it, and you'll be able not only to have 8, 16, 24, 32 bit per number, but ANY number size...

Answer (score 0):

I'd almost start looking at some variant of short-word encoding like a PkZip program.

Or even RLE encoding.

Or try to understand the usage of your data better.  Like, if these are all vectors or something, then there are certain combinations that are disallowed like, -1,-1,-1 is basically meaningless to a financial graphing application, as it denotes data outsides the graphable range.  If you can find some oddities about your data, you may be able to reduce the size by having different structures for different needs.